# nslookup does not work on certain IP address

Tags: reverse-dns, nslookup

when I gave nslookup 74.125.236.200

> Server:       192.168.5.11 Address:   192.168.5.11#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   200.236.125.74.in-addr.arpa   name = maa03s17-in-f8.1e100.net.
>
> Authoritative answers can be found from:
>   125.74.in-addr.arpa   nameserver = ns3.google.com.
>   125.74.in-addr.arpa   nameserver = ns1.google.com.
>   125.74.in-addr.arpa   nameserver = ns4.google.com.
>   125.74.in-addr.arpa   nameserver = ns2.google.com. ns3.google.com internet address = 216.239.36.10
>   ns2.google.com    internet address = 216.239.34.10
>   ns4.google.com    internet address = 216.239.38.10
>   ns1.google.com    internet address = 216.239.32.10

But when I gave  nslookup 1.0.0.245 I got the below reponse

> Server:       192.168.5.11 Address:   192.168.5.11#53
>
> ** server can't find 245.0.0.1.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN

But for the both above mentioned IP addresses I am able to find the domain name details when I used [IP2Locations](http://www.ip2location.com/demo)

Answer (score 2):

It just happens that there is no reverse DNS record defined for this particular IP address, so `nslookup` can't find anything.